# Kill a separate powershell script from the main script

Tags: powershell, automated-tests

I'm using a Powershell script to perform some automated testing on a web application.

Part of this script runs a small, separate script which basically monitors the web app for pop ups and closes them if they appear. It is called during the main script like so:

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist "-file C:\Users\Documents\Monitor.ps1"
```

At some point though I would like to close the monitor script, perform some commands, and then start the monitor script again.

Is there a way for me to kill the monitor script from the main, without closing the main script as well in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to save it to a variable:

```
$a = start-process notepad.exe -PassThru
$a.Id
10536
```

So you could later kill it.